# Some master slide text boxes accessible in presentation and some not

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I am creating a presentation and have designed a master slide with some layouts to do so. I have come up with the layout I want and it includes a footer with the title of the presentation, the date, and the slide number.

I've put those items into the slide master in the form of text boxes in the footer and want them to be inaccessible from outside of the master slide editor (i.e. the text not changeable and the text box not moveable/ selectable).

The textbox with the presentation name is inacessible as desired, however the text boxes for the date and the slide number are moveable and the text can be changed from within the standard presentation creator.

My question is now: How can I set the accessibility of the text boxes when creating the master slide and where can I see if they are accessible or not?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you included PPT's date/slidenumber/etc. placeholders on the master or its layouts, then they WILL be movable/editable on slides based on that master/layout. This is by design. Yes. It's a rather unfortunate design, but it's what we have.

Instead of using placeholders, just insert plain text boxes. For time/date, choose Insert | Text box, click where you want it, then while it's still selected and you have the text edit cursor, choose Insert | Date & Time (it may appear as a small icon on the right side of the "Text" group of the Insert tab. Choose the format for date and you're done. For slide number, do the same, but this time choose the Slide Number icon (usually just below the Time & Date icon).  It'll insert text that looks like <#> (but actually isn't quite the same; you can't make the magic by typing that yourself).